# When working with AVFoundation to record video, what is the best way to distinguish between actual video formats and still image formats?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avfoundation

I'm implementing a feature that will parse all of the available `AVCaptureDeviceFormat` objects in my `AVCaptureDevice` of type `AVMediaTypeVideo`.

What the code does is it looks at each format's max frame rate uses string versions of the frame rates as keys to a dictionary. So for example, on an iPhone 5s, I'll end up with a dictionary with keys "30", "60", and "120". The objects for these keys are the AVCaptureDevice formats that correspond to each frame rate AND have the best possible resolution for each frame rate.

Here's the code that does it:

```
 for (AVCaptureDeviceFormat *format in self.videoDevice.formats) {
        CMFormatDescriptionRef formatDescription = format.formatDescription;
        CMVideoDimensions dimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(formatDescription);
        FourCharCode mediaSubType = CMFormatDescriptionGetMediaSubType(formatDescription);
        BOOL fullRange = NO;

        /// We want only the formats with full range, so we use a bool to select for those.
        switch (mediaSubType) {
            case kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange:
                fullRange = NO;
                break;
            case kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange:
                fullRange = YES;
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"Unknown media subtype encountered in format: %@", format);
                break;
        }

        for (AVFrameRateRange *range in format.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges) {
            NSUInteger maxFrameRate = (NSUInteger)range.maxFrameRate;
            NSString *maxFrameRateAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)maxFrameRate];

            if (![self.fpsOptions objectForKey:maxFrameRateAsString]) {
                [self.fpsOptions setObject:format forKey: maxFrameRateAsString];

            } else {
                AVCaptureDeviceFormat *bestFormatForCurrentFrameRate = [self.fpsOptions objectForKey:maxFrameRateAsString];
                CMFormatDescriptionRef bestFDR = bestFormatForCurrentFrameRate.formatDescription;
                CMVideoDimensions bestDimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(bestFDR);
                /// We need to stop the 30 FPS setting from going above 1080 or app crashes when trying to save
                /// the video. Despite indications to the contrary, 2k+ resolutions are not valid video formats
                /// at least on an iPhone 5s.
                if (dimensions.height > bestDimensions.height && dimensions.height <= 1080 && fullRange == YES) {
                    bestFormatForCurrentFrameRate = format;
                    [self.fpsOptions setObject:bestFormatForCurrentFrameRate forKey:maxFrameRateAsString];
                    /// The following lines are necessary because in 240 fps capable devices, there isn't a dedicated 120 fps format. Per Apple's documentation, to record at 120, use a 240 fps format and manually set the frame duration (this is done in the changeFPS method).
                    if (maxFrameRate == 240) {
                        [self.fpsOptions setObject:bestFormatForCurrentFrameRate forKey:@"120"];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**THE PROBLEM**: Mixed in with the video formats are photo formats in disguise. For example, on my iPhone 5s, there are formats included in the array that list 30 fps as the max frame rate and have a resolution of 2592x1936. If I try to use such a format to record video, the app crashes because [I think] these formats are actually intended to be used to capture hi-res still images while recording video (a feature found in the built in camera app).

The problem is that there is no obvious way to distinguish between these photo formats and actual video formats (so far as I can tell). So if look at my code above, I simply cap the valid resolution at 1080.

The only thing I've found so far that might work is the value returned by 
`- isVideoStabilizationModeSupported:`. and testing a couple of different stabilization modes. Is this even a reliable way to do it? Is there a better way to do it? The goal is to make this code as dynamic as possible, so as to give the user access to all available video frame rates that their device is capable of AND record at the best possible resolution within each frame rate group.